# Understanding the program that reads a set of text lines and prints the longest in K &R's book

Tags: c, coding-style, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm reading K &R's book, section 1.9. The program for printing the longest line, from a given set of lines, is given as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000                   /* maximum input line length */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */

main()
{
   int len;                               /* current line length */
   int max;                               /* maximum length seen so far */
   char line[MAXLINE];                    /* current input line */
   char longest[MAXLINE];                 /* longest line saved here */
   max = 0;
   while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
      if (len > max) {
         max = len;
         copy(longest, line);
      }
   if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
      printf("%s", longest);
   return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
   int c, i;
   for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
      s[i] = c;
   if (c == '\n') {
      s[i] = c;
      ++i;
   }
   s[i] = '\0';
   return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
   int i;
   i = 0;
   while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
      ++i;
}
```

There is a problem in the `getline` function. If the `lim-1`th character of input line is not a newline then the `getline` will insert `'\0'` at `lim-1`th place leaving the `lim`th place unused (or empty).

I've removed this limitation by modifying the `getline` as,

```
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
   int c, i;
   for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
      s[i] = c;
   s[i] = c;
   s[i+1] = '\0';
   return i;
}
```

Is my version of `getline` correct?

If so, which version is fastest at run time, requires least memory, and uses least memory?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange would be a much better place for this question.

Comment: @DocBrown How many websites are there for programming? I do not want to know whether my code is correct or incorrect; I want a well explained and detailed answer like I got for my other questions on this site.

Comment: You don't want to know if your code is correct or incorrect? Honestly, your question reads "Is my version of getline correct?" - and that's a good question for codereview.stackexchange.  You will get better answers when you post your questions directly on the site which is best suited for it. And don't bother if you missed the correct site for the first time, lots of people here will tell you if you did so. You should either delete the question by yourself here, and then post it on the other site (in that order, to avoid crosspost!). Or you wait for migration.

Comment: @DocBrown Checking whether my version is correct or not is not the only thing that I want to know. I want to understand why did K&R made their code that way, that is what could be the benefits of their version over mine. If they can give me a detailed answer then I have no problem with migration.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I think codereview may not be a good fit for this question. I'm not a member there, but their tour says: "Don't ask about... troubleshooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets". Like I suggested on the [related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/273207/understanding-the-solution-of-exercise-1-16-of-kr-as-given-in-the-the-c-answer), this would be a better fit on SO, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question is still neither closed nor moved to another site... I'll answer it here.

The part about where (at what indices) you are allowed to write in a C buffer has been answered in a [related question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273237/142688), but I see have to repeat it here: you're only allowed to write at indices from 0 to `lim-1`, inclusively. You are not allowed to write to the `lim` index, in the sense that the behavior is undefined; what will happen in practice depends on whatever you happen to [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) to in memory. (You may also want to look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53878/how-to-explain-buffer-overflow-to-a-layman; even though it's not technically correct, the top answer there should give you the right intuition why overflows are a problem.)

In either version of `getline` from this question, the `for` loop can exit when `i==lim-1`. In your version of `getline` (the one lower/later in your question) you then write to `s[i+1]` unconditionally, which means that you write to `s[lim]`, which is a buffer overflow (aka buffer overrun).

K&R's version is a bit more subtle because if `i==lim-1` at the end of the loop, then `c` *cannot* be `'\n'`, so their `if (c == '\n') { s[i] = c; ++i; }` block does not execute in this case, so `i` is not incremented to be equal to `lim`, which makes the last assignment `s[i]` safe! In other words, ignoring (for the sake of making this easier to grasp) the part about `EOF`, a [postcondition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) for the `for` loop is that `(i==lim-1 && c!='\n' )||(i<lim-1 && c=='\n')`. To see why this is the case, you need to understand the [short-circuit behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of `&&`: when `i==lim-1`, the old value of `c` will be kept by not executing (short-circuiting) `c=getchar()`; furthermore, the previously obtained `c` is guaranteed to not be `\n` because in the contrary case the `for` loop would have been exited one iteration sooner, i.e. when `i<lim-1`. (The full postcondition of the `for` loop, not ignoring `EOF` is `(i==lim-1 && c!='\n' && c!=EOF)||(i<lim-1 && c==EOF)||(i<lim-1 && c=='\n')`.)

Comment: And single-byte overruns are hard to exploit by an attacker, but [not impossible](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2014/08/the-poisoned-nul-byte-2014-edition.html).

Comment: Now I understand it. I didn't know the short-circuiting of && operator, which caused me to have some potential misunderstanding of K&R's program. In `i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF` when `i < lim-1` becomes false then `(c=getchar())!=EOF` is not executed. Hence `lim -1`th character can never be `\n`. Is this _short-circuit_ concept explained in K&R?

Comment: I'll ask later how filling `lim`th index cause buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Program to print the length and content of the longest line in a text sep by new lines

#include <stdio.h>
char strcop(char *curr, char *bigg);
main()
{
    int cur=0, big=0,d, count=0;
    char curr[100], bigg[100];


    while((d=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
// Read the line till a new line is encountered
    if (d!= '\n')
    {
        curr[count] = d;
        count++;
        cur++;
    }

// compare with the big line after a new line is encountered and store the new big line
    else
    {   // comparing the length of lines
        if(cur>big)
        {
            big = cur;
            strcop(curr, bigg);
        }
        cur = count = 0;

    }


    }

for (int k =0 ; k<big; k++)
{
printf("%c", bigg[k]);
}
printf("\n");
//for (int k =0 ; k<big; k++)
//{
//printf("%c", curr[k]);
//}
//printf("count %d", count);
//printf("big %d", big);
//printf("cur %d", cur);
}

char strcop(char *curr, char *bigg)
{
    while(*curr)
    {
        *(bigg++) = *(curr++);
    }
}
```